# How to draw an UIImage using drawAtPoint after translating the image graphics context

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uikit

I have an image of a clock hand.  I am trying to created rotated versions of this image so that Ic an play it using animation (using `UIImageView's` `animatedImages` approach).

In the code below, I am seeing that if I apply a CGContextTranslateCTM to the image graphics context, the image is not drawn unless I increase the size I give to the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to make it bigger than image size.

Why is this needed?  I would think that all translation does is to move the definition of how the `drawAtPoint:` interprets where 0,0 is?

**Edited Code showing more details*

```
-(void) animatedClock
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(20, 100), NO, 0);

    UIBezierPath *clockHand = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [[UIColor yellowColor] setFill];
    [clockHand moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 20)];
    [clockHand addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10, 0)];
    [clockHand addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20, 20)];
    [clockHand fill];

    [clockHand removeAllPoints];
    [clockHand moveToPoint:CGPointMake(5, 100)];
    [clockHand addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(5, 20)];
    [clockHand addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(15, 20)];
    [clockHand addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(15, 100)];
    [clockHand closePath];
    [clockHand fill];


    UIImage *baseImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    NSLog(@"Image size is %@", NSStringFromCGSize(baseImage.size));
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //The screenshot will show baseimage, an arrow that is pointed upwards and at the top left of the screen
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:baseImage];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    //This code is just to see where 100, 100 is on screen
    UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100, 5, 5)];
    redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:redView];

    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index <= 8; index++)
    {
        //UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(baseImage.size, NO, 0); //If I keep this line then nothing is shown
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(500, 600), NO, 0); // If I keep this line I can see some of teh rotations
        CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextTranslateCTM(con, 100, 100); //I want the clock hands to be centered around 100, 100
        CGContextRotateCTM(con, 45*index*M_PI/180);
        [baseImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        imageView.opaque = YES;
        imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    }
}
```

[image: Image showing what is coming on screen. If I use the <code>UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(baseImage.size, NO, 0);</code> line instead of CGSizeMake(500,600) then all the rotated arrows don't show up]

Comment: "I am trying to created rotated versions of this image" How? There is no rotation anywhere in your code.

Comment: A great deal depends on what `baseImage.size` is. What is it?

Comment: @matt thanks.  The baseImage.size is 20,100.  Wanted to code simple, so initially just showed the part where I was translating the origin to 100, 100 to make the center of the clock.  I have edited my question to show the code that creates base Image.  Also, added screen shot that shows it (it is the arrow pointing upwards in the top left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am seeing that if I apply a CGContextTranslateCTM to the image graphics context, the image is not drawn

Of course. You draw at 0,0. But first you apply a translate CTM of 100,100. So you actually draw at 100,100. But the context is only 20 points wide. So you are drawing completely outside the context. There is no context outside the context, so nothing is drawn.

Comment: Might help you to read my book, where I actually solve the very problem you are working on http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_graphics_context_transforms

Comment: In any case your whole approach is wrong. Read the Animation chapter of my book, where I show how to rotate a clock hand (actually a compass arrow) by rotating a CALayer.

Comment: thanks.  This is what is confusing me.  I assumed that when I apply a transform to a context, the context itself shifts.  I.e the context is 20points wide but origin is at 100,100 after the shift.  So, anything drawn in the rect (100, 100, 20, 100) should be within the context.  Is that not the case?  Also, love your book on iOS programming fundamentals.  I am still wrapping around all the UI stuff in the bigger book (P.S: You should also write a Obj-C book along with the Swift book for a few more years!)

Comment: My idea is the following, I will create 8 versions of the UIImage, then add them to animatedImages of UIImageView and then animate it.  Is this approach correct?  Before I did all this, Wanted to first see the 8 images!

Comment: As I said in my answer, a translate CTM of 100,100 means that drawing at 0,0 actually draws at 100,100. And that is _all_ it means. And that is a good thing! You do not imagine that applying a rotate transform _rotates the context itself_, and it would be crazy (not to say meaningless) if it did. So why do you imagine that applying a shift transform _shifts the context itself_? The CTM, like everything else you do to the state of a graphics context, affects _the meaning of subsequent draw commands_. And that's all. Read the book link I pointed you to! Look at the example!

Comment: "Is this approach correct?" As I said, it's not what I would do. I would draw the clock hand into a layer (once) and rotate the layer. That way you get smooth animation, just like a clock (a clock does not jump in eight steps). However, you certainly _can_ do what you are doing, i.e. construct a series of images in code so that you can use them as frames of a UIImageView animation.

Comment: thanks.  Tried out a few things base don your comments and now I understand what all this translation means.  For beginners like me, maybe adding an illustration in your book showing the graphics context and how points are drawn after translation will help? Haven't reached the animation chapter, looking froward to it.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to understand how the nested transforms are achieving rotation around end of tail in the example.  I am able to get the point of the first one.  I guess rotation is around (0, 0) and after first one the tail (20, 100) is (0,0) and so rotation happens along it.  But how does the second reverse the translation when there is a rotation in between? `CGContextTranslateCTM(con, 20, 100);` and `CGContextTranslateCTM(con, -20, -100);` I would appreciate it if you could explain with some illustrations

Comment: "But how does the second reverse the translation when there is a rotation in between?" I think that is very well explained, both at that point in that book and in the earlier Views chapter where I discuss chaining of transforms in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @matt response, I did some experimentation. Running this code and the comments on what to expect may help some other beginners understand what is happening and how the drawing and translation interact.

```
#define CROSS_SIZE 10

-(void) conetxtTranslationDemos
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(CROSS_SIZE, CROSS_SIZE), NO, 0);

    //Creates an image that looks like multiply symbol.  Image is CROSS_SIZE by CROSS_SIZE wide
    UIBezierPath *cross = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [[UIColor redColor] set];

    [cross moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, CROSS_SIZE)];
    [cross addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CROSS_SIZE, 0)];
    //[cross removeAllPoints];
    [cross moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [cross addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CROSS_SIZE, CROSS_SIZE)];
    [cross stroke];


    UIImage *crossImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSLog(@"Image size is %@", NSStringFromCGSize(crossImage.size));

    //If you keep this you will see a cross image in top left of screen
//    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:crossImage];
//    [self.view addSubview:imageView];


    UIImageView *imageView;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100, 100), NO, 0);

    CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //Results in all drawings being 40 points displaced downwards from top left of screen
    CGContextTranslateCTM(con, 0, 40);

    //Results in a multiply which has its top left at 20, 40 (40 due to above translation)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(con, 20, 0);
    [crossImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    //Results in a multiply which has its top left at 0, 40 (40 due to original translation)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(con, -20, 0);
    [crossImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    //Results in a multiply which has its top left at 40, 40+20/sqrt(2) (40 due to original translation)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(con, 40, 20/sqrt(2));
    [crossImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    //Undo above translation
    CGContextTranslateCTM(con, -40, -20/sqrt(2));

    //Results in a add symbol instead of multiply.  This is because a point at (10, 10) is now (10, 10) in rotated axis, which is 0, 2*10/sqrt(2) in normal axis. That is why you see you will bottom enplane of the add co-incide with top left of cross drawn above at (40, 40+20/sqrt(2))
    CGContextTranslateCTM(con, 40, 0);
    CGContextRotateCTM(con, 45*M_PI/180);
    [crossImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

}
```